# Website Scraping with Python/General

Tags: python, url, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape a site and have several problems; for one it says my code is broken and i cannot seem to find a problem. I am also unsure what to put when looking for a regex when its . for example:

```
patFinderName = re.compile('<a rel.*href >(.*)</a>')
```

if the tag looks like:

```
"<A HREF="javascript:popUp('https://events...edu47&idy=2012','580','580')">
```

Finally how to a separate data when different pieces of info share similar tags such as

Here is my code:

```
from urllib import urlopen
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
import re

webpage = urlopen('https://events.bc.edu/cgi-bin/publish/webevent.cgi?cmd=listweek&y=2012&    m=05&d=20&de=1&tf=0&sib=1&sb=0&sa=0&ws=0&stz=Default&sort=e,m,t&cat=&swe=1&cf=list&set=1&cal=cal2').read

patFinderName = re.compile('<a rel.*href >(.*)</a>')
patFinderStartDate = re.compile('<span>(.*)</span>')
patFinderLocation = re.compile('<td><tr><tr><td>(.*)</tr></td><td><tr>')
patFinderInfo = re.compile('<tr><td><span>(.*)</span></TD></tr></table>')
patFinderLink = re.compile('<a rel.*href"(.*)">')

findPatName = re.findall(patFinderName,webpage)
findPatStartDate = re.findall(patFinderStartDate,webpage)
findPatLocation = re.findall(patFinderLocation,webpage)
findPatInfo = re.findall(patFinderInfo,webpage)
findPatLink = re.findall(patFinderLink,webpage)

listIterator = []
listIterator[:] = range(1,50)

for i in listIterator:
print findPatName[i]
print findPatStartDate[i]
print findPatLocation[i]
print findPatInfo[i]
print findPatLink[i]

articlePage = url(findPatLink[i]).read()
divBegin =articlePage.find('<div class="listeventName">')

article = articlePage[divBegin:(divBegin+1000)]

soup = BeautifulSoup(article)

Namelist = soup.findAll('a')
StartDatelist = soup.findAll('span')
Locationlist = soup.findAll('td')
infolist = soup.findAll('span')
linklist = soup.findAll('a')

for i in NameList:
    print i
    print "\n"

print "<!------------End Names-------------->"

for i in startDateList:
    print i
    print "\n"

print "<!------------End StartDate-------------->"

for i in locationList:
    print i
    print "\n"

print "<!------------End Locations-------------->"

for i in infoList:
    print i
    print "\n"

print "<!------------End Info-------------->"

for i in linkList:
    print i
    print "\n"

print "<!------------End Document-------------->"
```

Comment: Rather than using regular expressions to find a part of the page to run BeautifulSoup on, I'd suggest [using a `SoupStrainer`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs3/documentation.html#Improving%20Performance%20by%20Parsing%20Only%20Part%20of%20the%20Document).

Comment: "it says my code is broken". What's broken about it? What error message do you receive?

Comment: for i in startDateList:
       ^
    IndentationError: unexpected indent

Comment: icktoofay- Is there any operant that i could use that would regocnize the href="longlink">

Comment: @Alexander: [You can pass in a callable](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs3/documentation.html#match-callable) and check if it starts with `javascript:`: `SoupStrainer(lambda tag: tag.name.lower() == 'a' and tag['href'].startswith('javascript:'))` (note that this will raise an exception if there are any anchors without `href`s; that's an exercise for you)

Comment: @Alexander: However, note that all of the anchors you're looking for are in `div`s with classes of `listeventtitle`.

Comment: Charles, there's a Python library called [Beautiful Soup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) which parses HTML documents, making it easy to search and manipulate. You won't need regular expressions.

Comment: Better yet, politely ask your university to provide its calendar in a machine-readable format!